# What does "catkin build <pkg_name> --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" actually do?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently been exploring using these cmake-args to optimize my code. For the past few weeks I have just been running "catkin build <pkg_name>". Today when I ran "catkin build <pkg_name> --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" my code ran 10 times faster.

Should I always be running the second command instead with the build type explicitly mentioned as opposed to simply "catkin build <pkg_name>"? Is this a safe practice? I could not find much about this on the internet and I would greatly appreciate some advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294789/what-does-%22catkin-build-%3Cpkg_name%3E---cmake-args--dcmake_build_type=release%22-actually-do?/) by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2018-06-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-21**:
See #q172950 and #q71965 for what are almost duplicates btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually a CMake question, not really ROS-specific.

See [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) in the CMake documentation, and perhaps [this random post](https://codeyarns.com/2015/05/14/build-types-in-cmake/) about CMake build types for some more background.

The build type essentially just configures the compilers optimisation level.

> Should I always be running the second command instead with the build type explicitly mentioned as opposed to simply "catkin build <pkg_name>"? Is this a safe practice?

this is not easily answerable I believe.

The `Release` build type will set the following flags: `-O3 -NDEBUG` (at least for GCC type compilers). That is just about the maximum amount of optimisation and a debug features (such as asserts) are completely disabled.

If you're compiling your code for release purposes, then setting that build type might make sense. Especially in cases where code can make use of processor optimisations (such as SSEx, AVX, etc), allowing such optimisation might be beneficial. You've noticed quite a speed-up yourself, so that could point to a situation where it would make sense to set `Release` as the build type (but be careful to [do it correctly](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-and-the-default-build-type/) if you're contemplating doing it from within your `CMakeLists.txt`).

However, optimised builds will not contain any debug symbols, will not be easily debuggable and will have disabled a lot of things like assertions that would help you write correct code. `gdb` backtraces will be just about meaningless for optimised binaries (and not just because the symbols are missing).

So if you're still developing keeping the build type at its default makes more sense.

In cases where *some* optimisation is needed because otherwise your program doesn't work correctly (because it becomes too slow fi), the `RelWithDebInfo` build type might work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thank you very much for your response kind sir. I have been using std::cerr to debug my whole life. Now I have an alternative (y)

**Comment by [lukelu](https://answers.ros.org/users/56261/lukelu/) on 2020-09-26**:
We got the same issue, were wondering if we could add build type for certain pkg into CMakeLists.txt rather than using command line (i.e. catkin_make -pkg <pkg_name> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release).